# Error al compilar Angular con un Event - Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HtmlInputEvent'

Tags: angular, archivo, filereader

Estoy intentando compilar esta parte del codigo pero me da error.

Angular-Error:

```
src/app/admin/producto/create-producto-dialog.html:38:47 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HtmlInputEvent'.
  Types of property 'target' are incompatible.
    Type 'EventTarget | null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement & EventTarget'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement & EventTarget'.
        Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement'.

                         (change)="imgSelected($event)">
```

Codigo del component.ts

```
interface HtmlInputEvent extends Event{
  target : HTMLInputElement & EventTarget;
} 

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  public file :File;
  public imgSelect : String | ArrayBuffer;

  imgSelected(event: HtmlInputEvent){
    if(event.target.files  && event.target.files[0]){
        this.file = <File>event.target.files[0];

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = e => this.imgSelect = reader.result as String;
        reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
    }
  }
}
```

Code del Html

```
<div class="text-center">
      <img [src]="imgSelect || '../../../../assets/img/default.jpg'" class="rounded-circle img-responsive mt-2" width="128" height="128">
      <div class="mt-2">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" (change)="imgSelected($event)" type="file" style="width: 100% !important;">
      </div>>
  </div>
```

He probado añadiendo estas 3 líneas en tsconfig.json, pero no se soluciona el problema

"strict": true,
"strictPropertyInitialization": false,
"strictFunctionTypes": false

He probado a poner: HTMLInputElement & EventTarget | null;

Pero al añadir el null final, el event.target del IF me dice que es posible que sea null y tampoco me deja continuar.

He estado buscando información no obstante ninguna termina de resolver este problema.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: puede servirte?     imgSelected(event?: HtmlInputEvent){    let target= event?.target as HTMLInputElement;
        let eventFiles = (event?.target as HTMLInputElement)?.files?.[0]     ...........}

Comment: Mirando el stackoverflow en ingles he probado a poner

imgSelected(event: any), lo otro igual que lo tenía y funciona, pero lo que no entiendo es prk, la interfaz ya no la uso para nada y parece que funciona y no da error. ¿Alguna explicación? Gracias.

Comment: @CristianPrietoBeltran La interfaz es solo para que te autocomplete el código, sin interfaz, debes "averiguar" que propiedades tiene el objeto.

Comment: He tenido problemas a la hora de realizar el mismo proceso pero a formato PDF. Lo más sencillo es siempre utilizar any. El código pierde un poco de elegancia y robustez pero te permite solucionar el problema. En caso de que errores por null bastará con agregar signo de interrogación al final de cada atributo (event.target?.files[0]) para consultar si existe o es undefined.